# Java - Configuration/ information Management with hierarchy

Tags: java, configuration, hierarchy

I'm looking for a java tool to manage my clients configurations/ information.
My clients might have sub brands so in that case some attributes need to be inherit or override.

Here is a simple example of a configuration:

```
    Client 1
{
   address: Chicago USA
   Phone:   001.....
   Client 1.1 
   {

                address: LA USA
    }
    Client 1.2 
    {
                Phone: 005.....
    }
}
```

So in case you're fetching for client 1.1 you'll get:

```
Client 1.1
```

{

```
address: LA USA
Phone:   001.....
```

}

And when fetching for client 1.2 you'll get:
`Client 1.2 
{
    address: Chicago USA
    Phone: 005.....
}`

Thank you for the help

Comment: Properties files, maybe? Do you have a more specific problem we can discuss?

Comment: You could give [typesafe-config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#merging-config-trees) a try.

Comment: I need to build a configuration tree that when accessing a node i will get the attributes of the node and the nodes above in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by writing a thin wrapper class around any of several configuration file syntaxes (such as XML or Java properties files) by thinking in terms of scopes. Using "." as the scoping operator, "x.y.z" denotes variable "z" in scope "x.y". (Nested scopes correspond to nested elements if you are using XML.) You want to implement a `lookup(String scope, String localName)` operation. This operation will initially look for `localName` in the specified `scope`. If the variable is not present there, then the operation will look in the parent scope of `scope`, and keep working outwards to the global scope. Thus, calling `lookup("x.y", "z")` will try to find the variable `x.y.z`, then `x.z` and then `z`.

A different approach to the problem is to use the [Config4J](http://www.config4star.org/) configuration file parser (which I wrote). In particular, the `@copyFrom` command (in Config4J all keywords start with `@` to avoid keywords clashing with identifiers) enables you to copy the contents of one scope into another scope. This provides a mechanism for reuse of configuration information. See Chapter 2 ("Overview of Config4* Syntax") of the *Config4* Getting Started Guide* ([HTML](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-config4star-syntax.html), [PDF](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-getting-started-guide.pdf)) for details.